# MPI-2 on CPU vs GPU

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, openmpi

I am working on parallelising a code using MPI-2. It is successfully speeding up while I am using 8 core processors.

I was just wondering what would be the effect if I use GPUs for the same purpose instead of CPUs? According to my research so far, OpenMPI is compatible with GPUs and speed-up is only better if inter-processor communication is a lot as compared to CPU. Has anyone tried it out, or has any opinion on the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU parallelization is a totally different direction from MPI parallelization, in that GPU threads can't act like MPI ranks and make MPI calls - they're not really even threads in the sense needed. You can combine them, though, by calling GPU code in each rank of your MPI program.